# Avoiding a recursive call to .ajax();

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion

```
flagUpdateCustomer = 0;
$("input#checknames").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php.scripts/checknames.php',
        data: { firstname: $("input#firstname").val(),
            lastname: $("input#lastname").val(),
            address1: $("input#address1").val(),
            address2: $("input#address2").val(),
            city: $("input#city").val(),
            state: $("input#state").val(),
            zip: $("input#zip").val(),
            phone: $("input#phone").val(),
            email: $("input#email").val(),
            cell: $("input#cell").val()
        },
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        success: function (output) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(output);
            $("#existcustomers").empty();
            for (var iCnt = 0; iCnt < obj.length; iCnt++) {
                if (obj[iCnt].firstname == null) { obj[iCnt].firstname = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].lastname == null) { obj[iCnt].lastname = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].address1 == null) { obj[iCnt].address1 = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].address2 == null) { obj[iCnt].address2 = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].city == null) { obj[iCnt].city = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].state == null) { obj[iCnt].state = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].zip == null) { obj[iCnt].zip = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].phone == null) { obj[iCnt].phone = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].email == null) { obj[iCnt].email = ""; }
                if (obj[iCnt].cell == null) { obj[iCnt].cell = ""; }

                var newRow = $("<tr><td>" + obj[iCnt].firstname + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].lastname + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].address1 + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].address2 + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].city + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].state + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].zip + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].phone + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].email + "</td><td>" + obj[iCnt].cell + "</td></tr>").data('id',obj[iCnt].id);
                $("#existcustomers").append(newRow);
            }


            $("#existcustomers tr").hover(function () { $(this).addClass("highlight"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("highlight"); });

            $("#existcustomers tr").click(function () {


                $("#form-main").data('id', $(this).data('id'));

                $("input#firstname").val($(this).children(":eq(0)").text());
                $("input#lastname").val($(this).children(":eq(1)").text());
                $("input#address1").val($(this).children(":eq(2)").text());
                $("input#address2").val($(this).children(":eq(3)").text());
                $("input#city").val($(this).children(":eq(4)").text());
                $("input#state").val($(this).children(":eq(5)").text());
                $("input#zip").val($(this).children(":eq(6)").text());
                $("input#phone").val($(this).children(":eq(7)").text());
                $("input#email").val($(this).children(":eq(8)").text());
                $("input#cell").val($(this).children(":eq(9)").text());

                $("input#firstname").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#lastname").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#address1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#address2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#city").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#state").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#zip").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#phone").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#email").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("input#cell").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                $("#form-main").data('firstname', $("input#firstname").val());
                $("#form-main").data('lastname', $("input#lastname").val());
                $("#form-main").data('address1', $("input#address1").val());
                $("#form-main").data('address2', $("input#address2").val());
                $("#form-main").data('city', $("input#city").val());
                $("#form-main").data('state', $("input#state").val());
                $("#form-main").data('zip', $("input#zip").val());
                $("#form-main").data('phone', $("input#phone").val());
                $("#form-main").data('email', $("input#email").val());
                $("#form-main").data('cell', $("input#cell").val());

                //I am trying to determine how to call .ajax again to set my $_SESSION in PHP
                //A recursive call to .ajax does not seem to be a good option here
                //I was hoping to see somthing about an onchange or onupdate event in the jQuery docs
                //for .data() however I had no such luck. Perhaps could I use just the onchange()
                //event of #form-main? Essentially once the data is set in #form-main I have to call
                //.ajax again for add.customer.session.php. I am confused right now.

                //????????????????

                //
                //

                $('#form-main').css('background-color', 'green');
            });
        }


    });  


});
```

I have a call to `.ajax()` and inside of that call there is set a `$("#existcustomers tr").click()` and inside of that click the most logical way for to handle things would be another call to `.ajax()` inside of the first however I am looking for another option. I am wondering at this point if there is some easy way to hook an event to `#form-main` and run some code after `.data()` sets the data to `#form-main`. As always thank you all in advance for any suggestions or commentary related to this code!

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.

Comment: If you want to avoid having ajax calls inside each other, you can use non-anonymous functions. This way, you define your callback in a different place than your call to ajax.

Comment: shouldn't be adding click handler for all rows within the ajax success callback..will be compounding click handlers every time ajax request made. Use `on()` to delegate click handler to allow for future elements. Or just apply the click handler to new rows as they are added `newRow.click...`

Comment: This isn't technically recursion and there is no technical problem with doing it this way.  The success handler for the first ajax call happens AFTER the .click() handler has exited.  You are chaining successive ajax calls - not recursing.

Comment: sepoto, I know you have an answer but please read the comment by @charlietfl above. His is the most important piece of advice you have been offered, though it addresses an aspect not raised in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a recursive problem here. You just have chained ajax calls. This would really only be a problem if it could loop around around and call the original action again.

Since know that your first ajax call will make another ajax call, you could make both at the same time as an asynchronous call or if you have control over the server API, allow for both types of data to set/requested in one call.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply. I am requesting to leave this open while I do some testing.

Comment: I added the call to .ajax inside the call to .ajax and tried running the code but now $("#form-main").data('id') is coming in as an undefined variable when I catch the echo from PHP.

Comment: If your second Ajax call does indeed use data from the first Ajax call then your simple answer is then to chain them. If this is the case and you can't simplify it, then you shouldn't worry about having chained calls.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using $_POST on the server side so the method of .ajax had to be changed off its default setting. No problems at all now. I have to mark your answer as the correct answer. It is a very good answer.